# http(s) non-www to www redirect nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

This is my config:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    domain.com www.domain.com;
   return         301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

#server {
#       listen          443 ssl;
#       server_name     domain.com;
#       return          301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
#}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ...
    { ssl stuff }
    ...
    server_name www.domain.com;
    ...
```

With this solution ( second server block commented ) i am able to         successfully redirect `http://domain.com` and `http://www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` and both `https://domain.com` `https://www.domain.com` are working correctly. 
The problem starts when i uncomment second server block to enable redirect from `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`. Then its broken.

Curl -v -I output:

```
$ curl -v -I https://www.domain.com
[15:08:42]
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.domain.com/
*   Trying 8.8.8.8...
* Connected to www.domain.com (8.8.8.8) port 443 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: What do you mean "both `https://domain.com` `https://www.domain.com` are working correctly?" What else do you have in third block, i.e. did you try to put a `server_name domain.com` or some kind of alias in there?

Comment: Hi @Colt, I've updated origin question there is server_name www.domain.com in third block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't included SSL certificates, etc. for `https://domain.com` in second block, and so it can't operate on 443

Comment: You are right, I've added settings for ssl from the third block and its working, i don't understand how, in most tutorials I've saw there is nothing like that. 

But still thanks for help! :)

Comment: @xrep To avoid repeating the SSL configurations, you may keep the SSL configuration outside the server block but inside the http block, assuming the SSL configuration applies to all the domains hosted in the server.

Comment: @Pothi it does not look like that is the case, though, as half of the domains are http on port 80